# Can opposing centripetal forces help us play catch in a space station?

Tags: centrifugal-force

Let's say we are inside a wheel in our brand-new space station, which spins to simulate gravity, using the centrifugal force. We decide to celebrate our ground-breaking success by play catch in space.

We immediately realize the path of the ball gets annoyingly skewed by the rotation, making for a frustratingly difficult game of catch. We decide this won't do and go about fixing it.

After some thougthful discussion, we use our unlimited resources to build an additional wheel inside the original wheel that spins counter to it, compensating the skewing of the ball being thrown, so we can play a proper game.

What would happen? Would it work?

Comment: So the inner wheel is at rest relative to to the center of the space station? Does your proper game just mean no centrifugal force effects?

Comment: That's the basic idea: you would want to play as if you were in your own back-yard.

Comment: Then you would need to create a uniform "gravitational field". You wouldn't want to just cancel centrifugal effects.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it would work - sort of.

If the second wheel spun at a rate that undid the rotation of the first wheel, there would be no rotation. It would be as if there were no wheels.

The ball would be seen to go in a straight line, but you would be weightless.